# Ajax working only one account on wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I have an issue when using Ajax in WordPress. Everything is fine when I'm using the main account (account with which I created database for my WordPress).

But when I am using another administrator account, Ajax does not work.

Comment: Are both users logged in when you test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use the **no priv** option for the user who are not logged in.

```
wp_ajax_nopriv_<function_name>
```

Here function name is calling function name called from javascript/jquery.

```
$('.selector').on('click',function(){

        var data={
            action: "function_name",// function name used with no_priv
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data,function(res){

                console.log(res); //print the output

        });
});
```

Hope this will help you.